Distortions in Wide-Angle Shots Using CameraX on Android: Any Solutions?
I'm capturing wide-angle shots using CameraX on Android. However, I've noticed distortions, like a fisheye effect, in these wide-angle shots. Do you have any suggestions for a solution?
Thanks

Are you talking about perspective distortion? If so, I don't think there is a way to fix it with CameraX/Camera2 API.
